# Measure the horizontal distance between two nodes and apply to relative placement between two other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, calc

I would like to measure the horizontal distance between two nodes `A` and `B`, and then place another node `Y` the same horizontal distance from `X`, but aligned vertically with `v0`.

What's the syntax for that?

*Update:* It's the horizontal space between the *text* that I want to hold constant.  I can measure the distance with Paul Gaborit's answer slightly modified, but how do I place `Y` so that `Y.west` aligns with `p`?

*Update2:* Solution is to put `[anchor=west]` on the node.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (v3) at (0,2) {};
  \node (v2) at (0,1.5) {};
  \node (v1) at (0,.5) {};
  \node (v0) at (0,0) {};
  \node (h1) at (1,0) {};
  \node (h2) at (1.5,0) {};

  \node (A) at (v3) {A};
  \node (B) at (h1|-v2) {B};
  \node (X) at (h2|-v1) {XXXXX};
 
  \coordinate (p) at ($(X.east)+($(B.west)-(A.east)$)$);
  \node[anchor=west](Y) at (p |- v0) {YYYYY};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (v3) at (0,2.5) {};
  \node (v2) at (0,1.5) {};
  \node (v1) at (0,.5) {};
  \node (v0) at (0,0) {};
  \node (h1) at (1,0) {};
  \node (h2) at (1.5,0) {};

  \node (A) at (v3) {A};
  \node (B) at (h1|-v2) {B};
  \node (X) at (h2|-v1) {X};
 
  \coordinate (p) at ($(X)+($(B)-(A)$)$);
  \node(Y) at (p |- v0) {Y};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Once again I fall into the trap of making my MWE too minimal. In my document, these nodes have names of varying widths. So I think I want `\coordinate (p) at ($(X.east)+($(B.west)-(A.east)$)$);` And then I want `Y.west` aligned with that. How do I place `Y`? (That is, I want horizontal space between the _text_ of `X` and `Y` to be the same as that of `A` and `B`.)

Comment: Got it, put [anchor=west] on the node.

Comment: @dedded To align texts, try also the `base west`, `base east`, `mid west` and `mid east` anchors...